# Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused

Tags: android, sdk, fetch

Using Android SDK Manager when I try to update it just gives the following messages about not being able to connect.  I've tried disabled firewall and anti malware.  I also tried to run as admin and move to c:\android.  I'm running windows 7 64bit.  I've also tried forcing etc.

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Connection to refused
Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Connection to refused

Comment: Are you able to open these URLs in your browser?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using IE9 and it opens right up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27388755/3830694

Comment: it should not be closed. please reopen this question.

Comment: same as OMGPOP. This question is clear and is a problem that can be fixed…

Comment: for newer versions of android studio which sdk manager isn't standalone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645087/error-in-updating-android-sdk-org-xml-sax-saxparseexception

Answer (score 41):

Follow the following steps if you are using **proxy server**:

1. Open Eclipse
2. Window >> Android SDK Manager >> Option
3. Input your proxy server and port.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what to write in proxy server and port?

Comment: @userX Your "proxy address" or "proxy ip" and "port no" for non-browser application. Consult your network admin for these params.

Answer (score 35):

Go to Internet Explorer, into options -> connections -> Lan settings. There should be an automatic config script option, copy the url, paste it into a browser, this downloads the config file, opened the file up in notepad and there will be a proxy address and a port number in there like 192.234.10.23:88 paste the address into the proxy field and the port (88) into the port field in the Android SDK manager Tools -> Options dialog.

Answer (score 26):

GoTo Tools -> Options in SDK Manager. Check https to force to http and try... Worked for me

Comment: Worked for me. Not great from a security perspective, but I don't see why it fails otherwise…

Answer (score 8):

I got the solution for the Android Studio installation after trying everything that I could find on the Internet. If you're using Android Studio and getting this error:

Find `[Path_to_Android_SDK]\sdk\tools\android.bat`.
In my case, it was in `C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\android.bat`.

Right-click it, hit `Edit`, and scroll all the way down to the bottom.

Find where it says: `call %java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG% ...`

Replace that with `call %java_exe% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true %REMOTE_DEBUG% ...`

Restart Android Studio/SDK and everything works. This fixed many issues for me, including being unable to fetch XML files or create new projects.

Comment: I found that you need to add `"-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` after  the `%REMOTE_DEBUG%` statement. Also, added double-quotes around the setting to match other `-D` statements already in batch file.

Answer (score 7):

Run SDK Manager as Admin will solve your problem

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

After 7 long hours of searching I finally found the way!!
None of the above solutions worked, only one of them pointed towards the issue!

If you are on Win7, then your Firewall blocks the SDK Manager from retrieving the addon list.
You will have to add "android.bat" and "java.exe" to the trusted files and bingo! everything will start working!!

Comment: THIS was the answer! Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Do the following.

1. Close the sdk manager and eclipse.
2. Go to the folder where you have stored your adt.
3. In that adt folder you'll find a folder known as tools.
4. Make a copy  of the contents of that folder and paste it in a folder called copytools.
5. Now go to the command prompt and go to the location of the copytools.
6. Then execute the command android.bat the sdk manager will start.
7. Now update all the plugins you want. It'll update your original folder.
8. After the update delete the copy.

Enjoy. Hope this helps.

Comment: in linux, just running the same code as administrator has solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same problem below is the solution that worked for me

First Go to Android SDK Manager then

select Tools then,

select Options

then check the box "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."

hope it will help you also.

Answer (score 2):

As srijan said,

Check your actual proxy settings, if you are using a proxy script to access the web, it might be (by default) : proxy serveur: proxy / proxy port: 8080

You may have these informations in Inter Explorer, Options, Connexions settings ..
Worked for me

You may also need to add rules to your firewall/antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows 7, simply run Eclipse with Admin privilege will solve this issue.

Just tried this on my Windows 7 64bits OS.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you need to add proxy setting in your SDK Manager
GoTO->Windows->SDK Manager->Tool->Otions
There give SERVER: proxy and PORT:8080

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue running within a corporate network.  I added a DNS entry for google DNS at 8.8.8.8, then my own corporate DNS server below this.  Worked great after that.

Comment: How to set DNS entry for google and where ? Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

just run the android sdk manager , go to tools then obtions and a new window will apears 
mark the three checkboxes at the bottom and close it
it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and it costed me all day :-(
I tried all of the suggestions above, but none of them did the work.

At the end, I uninstalled Comodo Firewall, and everything worked fine.
Before uninstalling, I tried to add the all relevant files as trusted application in the comodo firewall, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with MacOS.  I had to uncheck "use download cache" under Android SDK Manager preferences.  This worked.  I also recreated the cache folder and set my user as the owner then check user download cache.  This also worked.

Answer (score -4):

Using freegate as agent in China.
Run Freegate,latest version.
Run SDK Manager, Tools -> Options, Proxy Server 127.0.0.1, Port 8580.
I hope it will help you.