# Failed to fetch android repository files from SDK manager

Tags: android, macos, https, adt

I am getting the following messages while Running the Android SDK Manager through eclipse.

**Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: File not found**

But i am able to open them through the browser

System and software information.

1) Mac osx 10.8.5 (x86)
2) Latest Android SDK for mac
3) Java Run Time Environment JRE 7

I have tried with the all options which were explained in the following URL

[Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml, reason: Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181168/failed-to-fetch-url-https-dl-ssl-google-com-android-repository-addons-list-1-x)

Answer (score 2):

The reason may be related with no access to "$HOME/.android" folder.
Details [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76268)

Comment: `android update sdk --no-ui` says: "File not found" but actually `$HOME` was not writable -.- grrrrr, thanks @mapcuk !

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal
Go to `~/android-sdks/tools (your users local directory/android-sdks/tools)`
Run the android sdk manager as Super User - 
sudo android
Collect all the repository details and exit 
Now run as your normal user via eclipse.

If this failed then try this.

You can  just fix it by running eclipse as an administrator:
In the Terminal, type `"sudo <your installation folder>/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse"` and if needed tick "Force https://.. sources to be fetched using http://...

It worked for me on my Mac(OS X 10.8.5).

Comment: I have executed android unix executable file through terminal as Super User sudo.
Now i got it as expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had Windows VM on MacOSX and probably problems with UNC paths, spaces in names or rights on folders.

The solution was not to use Download cache (uncheck it).

Answer (score 0):

**For linux or ubuntu users:**

From the command-line you can directly trigger an update by
executing:

```
sudo <your sdk path> tools/android update sdk --no-ui
```