# Android SDK Manager shows only a few packages

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I've installed Android studio successfully, but SDK manager shows only a few installed packages. Firewall on computer is off, force: https://... option is set and manager log shows that add-ons-listed-2 and repository-10 was successfully loaded. But only Android 5.0.1 (API 21) was loaded and a few Extras such as Google Repository, Android support repository and HAXM installer was installed. There is no NotInstalled package.
I don't know what can do else. Any Idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I mean that there is not another APIs like API19 or API17 and so on, and there is no for example Google USB Driver in Extras folder.

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181168/failed-to-fetch-url-https-dl-ssl-google-com-android-repository-addons-list-1-x