# error in updating android sdk (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, sax, saxparser

There is a common problem in using *android sdk manager* but there isn't any solution for this problem all over the web even in the *stackoverflow*:

for updating components of android sdk I write in the command prompt:

```
C:\sdk\tools\bin>sdkmanager --list
```

the erros that appear are these:

```
Warning: Errors during XML parse:
Warning: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
Warning: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
Warning: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 62; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.]
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
Warning: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
Warning: Failed to parse source list at https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
```

Please everyone who have experienced the same problem or everyone who know the solution, help this problem be solved.

[image]

Comment: i have same error also in one day ago trying to solve this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to open https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml url in your web browser. This url opens a page containing a very lengthy xml file. If the *This product is not available in your country* message from *Google* appeared, you must use a *VPN*. If you could open the above url after using *VPN* then do following.

In *Android Studio* (2.3.3) open Settings from `File>Settings [Ctrl+Alt+S]`. In the left panel go to `Appearance & Behavior>System Settings>HTTP Proxy`. Here select *Auto-detect proxy settings* radio button (*No proxy* is selected by default). Now (while your *VPN* is enabled) you should see new android SDK packages that are availaible for download (that weren't availaible before doing this step for me) in `Appearance & Behavior>System Settings>Android SDK`.